# Multiple DocumentRoot in XAMPP or Apache

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost, host

What would be the best way to set up XAMPP so that when I go to

`http://localhost1` it access the folder `C:\localhost1`

and when I type

`http://localhost2` it access the folder `C:\localhost2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done a response yesterday that should fit your needs:
[Modify htaccess file for two sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594800/modify-htaccess-file-for-two-sites/4597667#4597667)

Answer (score 0):

Use Alias in apache conf

http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=36801

[Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs)